# CheckPoint Endpoint Security VPN client co-existing with Windows VPN

Tags: windows-7, vpn, checkpoint

Hey guys, I work as a consultant for a firm with a Checkpoint firewall. I have downloaded and installed the Checkpoint Endpoint Security VPN client. During the installation, I answered no to any questions pertaining firewall etc. - I just wanted the VPN client itself.

However, after the installation, I am no longer able to use any of my pre-existing Windows VPN client connections. It does not matter whether the Checkpoint UI is running or not - shutting down the client does not fix the problem.

Uninstalling Checkpoint VPN on the other hand fixes the problem.

Does anyone know if it is possible to have both VPN clients work while being installed simultaneously? I don't need them to stay connected simultaneously, just avoiding to install/uninstall the Checkpoint client every time I have to use it is perfectly good.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In 2003 I ran into this issue as well: the Checkpoint IPSec VPN client was interfering with the normal Windows IPSec service; the **only way** that I could get the windows IPsec stuff working again was to completely remove the Checkpoint IPSec driver (plus a reboot).
I'm not entirely surprised that this "feature" of the Checkpoint client is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Uneducated guess: The VPN client also installs a Windows Service that was still running after closing the client that was blocking other clients from working?